# Mudança constante de datas no CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, data

Tenho um site desenvolvido em PHP e CodeIgniter, nunca trabalhei com PHP nem com CodeIgniter, apenas com JavaScript.

O problema é que a data dos anúncios do site está constantemente se atualizando, o que era para ser fixo, ele altera praticamente a cada 15 dias.

A data de cadastro de clientes também se encontra completamente errada, juntamente com a data de último acesso, deveria informar a data que o usuário logou por último, e de todos estão com as datas (31/12/1969 21:00:00 )

Achei que fosse algo relacionado ao timezone do banco de dados, mas está tudo certo, alguém sabe como verifico e encontro este erro?

Comment: Seja mais especifico na sua pergunta. "A data de cadastro de clientes também se encontra completamente errada" - Dê um exemplo de uma data que ficou errada e do código que gerou essa data

Comment: verifique a documentação, deve ser algo no `helper` https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html

Comment: Provavelmente o script está gerando um padrão de data que o banco não reconhece, e pra evitar interrupção, ele grava o formato default. E eu aposto que o banco é MySQL/MariaDB. *Tem que mostrar o código*. Só de ouvir falar fica difícil...